# multer and formik - Can't upload a file

Tags: reactjs, postman, multer, formik

I've got a problem with multer and Formik. When I test with Postman my upload route, to upload an image in a post, it works perfectly, save the imageUrl in MySQL and save the image in the correct folder. But when I try to do this in my real front end with formik, the file just don't want to upload as a file, but only as a string. But Form has "encType=multipart/form-data".

**NPM give me this error message :**

"image: req.file.path,

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')"

I'm struggling with this for one entire day now, so I will put right there everything's needed to explain to you my problem:

**route post config :**

```
router.post("/", validateToken, multer, async (req, res) => {
const postBody = {
title: req.body.title,
postText: req.body.postText,
image: req.file.path,
username: req.user.username,
UserId: req.user.id,
};

 postBody.imageUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/images/${
 req.file.filename
}`;

 await Posts.create(postBody);
 res.json(postBody);
});
```

**front end formik part :**

```
<Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    onSubmit={onSubmit}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
  >
    <Form
      className="formContainer"
      action="/"
      encType="multipart/form-data"
    >
      <label>Title: </label>
      <ErrorMessage name="title" component="span" />
      <Field autoComplete="off" name="title" placeholder="(Ex. Title...)" />
      <label>Post: </label>
      <ErrorMessage name="postText" component="span" />
      <Field
        autoComplete="off"
        name="postText"
        placeholder="(Ex. Post...)"
      />
      <input type="file" name="image"></input>

      <button type="submit"> Create Post</button>
    </Form>
  </Formik>
```

**axios part :**

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
console.log(data);
axios
  .post("http://localhost:3001/posts", data, {
    headers: {
      accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
      "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(data);
    navigate("/");
  });
};
```

And Data console.log in google inspector :

[data console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGnJJ.png)

Thx in advance guys !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using a Formik field to get the file input, try setting the `onChange` manually, and update the Formik state with an on change handler.

Something like:

```
<input 
  type="file" 
  name="image"
  onChange{(e) => {
    setField("image", e.target.files[0])
  }}
/>
```

`setField` is a formik function that should allow you to give it the actual file.  Formik doesn't seem to support files natively so this workaround appears necessary.

Links:
[codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lkkjpr5r7?file=/index.js:1793-1806)
[setField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388855/how-do-i-implement-a-custom-handlechange-function-on-formik)
[custom onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638559/reactjs-formik-file-upload)

Comment: I've tried this one but it says "setfield" is not defined ... I'm pretty sure i'm forgetting something but I can't figure it out and it makes me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="file" name="image" onChange={uploadFile}/>`

```
const [file, setFile] = React.useState();

const uploadFile = (event) => {
  if (!event.target.files?.length) return;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

  fileReader.onloadend = () => {
  const content = fileReader.result;
  if (content) {
    setFile(content); 
  }
};
```

More about fileReader, readAsDataURL, (on)loadend, and rest, you can read here:

- FileReader https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader

Comment: I've found another solution with react states, and it worked, but now, when I want to do the same thing but to upload a new image in the same post, I get this same error, so I will try your solution tonight and I let you know ! Thx !